# Prevent Concurrent Editing of a List Item

Tags: sharepoint, concurrency, moss

In Sharepoint MOSS multiple users can edit the same item in a sharepoint list at the same time…the first person to save their edit “wins”.

Is there a way to prevent this, to lock the list item while it is being edited?

NB:  This refers to a custom list -Not a document in a document library

Comment: I don't think there's a safe definition of "while an item is being edited" here. Anyone could open an item's edit form and leave it sitting there forever. Surely you don't want to lock out other users at that point, do you?

Comment: That is the obvious downside of the "pessimistic locking" strategy that we are looking to implement on a couple of our lists.  I realise that the "out the box" optinistic concurrency is far more useful in most circumstances - but not always.

I am imagining a message along the lines of "You cannot edit this item as it is currently locked by 'Bob Smith' would be fine for us.

Comment: Mondo, do you have MOSS enterprise? You could also knock up an infopath form to replace the custom list's webform. Of course, you'd have to use a content type then (but that's always good practice). With infopath you'll have more options; calling out to a list in the root of the site collection containing "locks" for example and displaying a message inline.

Comment: Hi xOn - sadly we only have standard, but your post has got me thinking along the right lines (I hope).
Would it be possible to customise the EditForm.aspx using javascript (jQuery for SP maybe - http://spservices.codeplex.com) to:
1) OnLoad - check if the current listitem ID is in the "locks" list you describe
2) If it is present then display warning message, else add the current username and listitem ID to the locks list.  
3) Remove the entry from the locks list on page unload.

Sounds possible?  

Thanks for your help on this!!!

Comment: I hava similar requirement as yours ,I have googled a lot , but could not find a good post. Would you be able to help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible - checkin/checkout is only supported for list items with an associated SPFile object (images, pages, documents - essentially everything that derives from SPDocumentLibrary)

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that, all custom. As Oisin said on his post the native check-in/check-out engine needs a file associated.

Ideas:

**Javascript**

- Modified EditForm.aspx file, embedded in a List Template, XmlHttpRequest checks for a *"Checked-out Items List"* repository, expires/remove the check after 10-20 minutes of inactivity from the user currently editing the file.

**.NET**

- Event Handlers: I have not checked but the ItemUpdating Event Type could stop you from updating it if the Modified date changed since you opened the item, saying the item was modified while being edited and need to be updated (cloning the behavior of aspx/publishing pages in SharePoint)

**Infopath**

- I noticed you said you dont have the enterprise version, still your users could have the InfoPath client on their machines and fill the form locally.

Now lets start the fun :)

**Empty Document Template**

- You can hack your way to create a super "Add Item" button that uploads/creates a new Document Library Item with an empty document (.txt) and redirect the user directly to the Edit Properties form. I did this when I replaced the "Change Image" in the My Sites profile with a Document Library.

**Word Document**

- Word 2007 can create documents similar to forms where the user can only fill the exact fields you want, so can excel (Infopath was created because users were using these programs for forms).